# duda sobre el funcionamiento de carga del html (codigo funciona pero quero saber por qué)

Tags: javascript, html, function

tengo un js con una función que hace que me calcule unos determinados altos para que cuando ponga esas clases en una etiqueta me calcule su altura del porcentaje según el alto de la pantalla:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    resizeOneTime();

}, false);

function resizeOneTime() {
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

$('.layer').css("height","auto");
if ($('.layer').height() < height) $('.layer').css("height",height+"px");

var layerv95 = Math.floor(height*95/100);
$('.layerv95').css("height",layerv95+"px");
$('.layermaxv95').css("max-height",layerv95+"px");
...
}
```

ahora, si cargo esa funcion en el head del html, cuando cargo la pantalla de laptop si me funciona, pero si lo cargo como movil desde el inspector del navegador, no me calcula las alturas correctamente HASTA que no redimensiono la pantalla.

si lo pongo en el body onload="resizeOneTime()" me ocurre lo mismo

si lo pongo como

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        resizeOneTime();
</script>
```

ocurre lo mismo.

PERO si pongo la funcion en el body y al final del body la vuelvo a cargar, si me pone la altura correctamente de primeras tanto en movil como en desktop (resolucion me refiero, no de dispositivo)

pues mi pregunta es para saber el por que así si me funciona pero si cargo la función una sola vez solo me pone bien la altura en desktop y en movil no, hasta que redimensiono.

Comment: Cuando tratas de ejecutar la función `resizeOneTime();` con un script dentro de `<head></head>` los elementos involucrados todavía no han sido renderizados por el navegador y por eso es que no funciona. Pero si pones ese script  hasta abajo, antes de `</body>`, el navegador primero renderiza la página y después ejecuta el código. Por eso se recomienda poner los scripts al final o dentro de un evento `DOMContentLoaded`, para asegurar que los elementos existen al momento de ejecutar el código.

Comment: gracias!!, el caso es que si no pongo en <body onload="resizeOneTime();"> la función, y al final del body, justo antes de </body> pongo la misma función que se ejecute, no funciona, es decir, lo tengo que poner en los dos puntos del body para que funcione...